# creating a main menu for a mobile app in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm have trouble figuring out how to begin a code that displays a main menu. I want this main menu to display 5 different options that when on of them is clicked, it open that page/option. I also have Kivy installed, and the overall goal is to make a mobile app. My python experience is low, so I haven't actually written out any code for this goal but I have a full layout of what I want the app to look like.

Updated:

This is what I have so far.

```
mainMenu = {}
mainMenu ['1'] = 'Option 1'
mainMenu ['2'] = 'Option 2'
mainMenu ['3'] = 'Option 3'
mainMenu ['4'] = 'Option 4'
mainMenu ['5'] = 'Option 5'

print(mainMenu)
while True:
    selection = input()
    if selection == '1':
        print('Page 1')
    elif selection == '2':
        print('Page 2')
    elif selection == '3':
        print('Page 3')
    elif selection == '4':
        print('Page 4')
    elif selection == '5':
        print('Page 5')
        break
```

Comment: Try to write some code and then if you get stuck share your code with the community so we can help you get untangled.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do my best and share what I come up with

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! How exactly should an answer to your question look like? Do you want us to write the code for you? Do you want to get links to tutorials? Stackoverflow works best if you have a specific problem which you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the example below and modify it as per your requirementst. I recommend reading the documentation abound [Kivy Dropdown list](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html).

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.config import Config


class SubMenu(DropDown):
    pass


class MainMenu(FloatLayout):

    def display_selected_submenu(self, instance, x):
        print("Page " + x)


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Drop-Down List Demo"
    Config.set("graphics", "width", "800")
    Config.set("graphics", "height", "480")

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<CustomButton@Button>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 40
    font_size: 18


<SubMenu>:
    on_select: app.root.display_selected_submenu(self, args[1])

    CustomButton:
        id: button1
        text: 'Open'
        txt: "1"
        on_release: root.select(self.txt)

    CustomButton:
        id: button2
        text: 'Save'
        txt: "2"
        on_release: root.select(self.txt)

    CustomButton:
        id: button3
        text: 'Exit'
        txt: "3"
        on_release: root.select(self.txt)

<MainMenu>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0,0
            size: self.width, self.height

    Button:
        id: mainbutton
        text: "File Menu"
        font_size: 20
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 150, 50
        top: root.top
        on_release: Factory.SubMenu().open(self)
```

### Output

[image: Exit Selected & Page 3 printed on console]