# Menu set in left side

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## menu.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv_str = Builder.load_string('''
ActionBar:
    pos_hint: {'top':1}
    ActionView:
        use_separator: True
        ActionPrevious:
            title: 'Example App'
            with_previous: False
        ActionButton:
            text: 'File'
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Edit'
        ActionGroup:
            text: 'Tools' 
            mode: 'spinner'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Tool1'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Tool2'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Tool3'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Tool4'
''')


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv_str

if __name__ =='__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

[image: set menu in left side]

How to set menu left side.Now these menu coming right side.How to set in left side instead of example app.After that add small icon add under menu(second row).

first row - File Edit Tools(with sub menu)
Second row - icon1 icon2 icon3

Comment: You might want to use Kivy Dropdown List to create menu. Please refer to my post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312856/creating-a-main-menu-for-a-mobile-app-in-python

Comment: hey, thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to switch sides on the actionbar, at least not without extensively changing it. Therefor, here is a solution which has buttons on the left. It is not as beautiful. You need to make sizing and background colors nice by yourself.

[image]

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


class CustDrop(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustDrop, self).__init__( **kwargs)
        self.select('')


kv_str = Builder.load_string('''


BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
            Color:
                rgb: (1,1,1)
        size_hint_y:1
        Button:
            text: 'File'
        Button:
            text: 'Edit'


        Button:
            id: btn
            text: 'Tools'
            on_release: dropdown.open(self)
            #size_hint_y: None
            #height: '48dp'  


        CustDrop:

            id: dropdown

            Button:
                text: 'First Item'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '48dp'
                on_release: dropdown.select('')
                on_release: print('First Item pressed')

            Button:
                text: 'First Item'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '48dp'
                on_release: dropdown.select('')


            Button:
                text: 'Third Item'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '48dp'
                on_release: dropdown.select('')

        Label:
            size_hint_x: 4

    Label:
        size_hint_y: 9

''')


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv_str

if __name__ =='__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

I cheated somewhat by passing the empty string to the select method. Probably, DropDown was not originally intended to be used that way.